# Selecionar e calcular horas com datatype varchar

Tags: select

Olá, por data, preciso fazer a maior hora menos a menor hora de X pessoas.

1 Como selecionar a maior e menor por uma data? Já tentei muita coisa, posso postar aqui as tentativas.

2 Os dados estão gravados como varchar, como achar a diferença entre horas/ minutos? Também já tentei muita coisa, posso postar.

Desde de já, obrigado.

```html
DataAcesso HoraAcesso
20150401 81822
20150401 81855
20150401 102835
20150401 105401
20150401 123939
20150401 125526
20150401 152418
20150401 152522
20150401 162554
20150401 162752
20150401 180024
```

Comment: Você quer fazer esse calculo no SQL mesmo ou está utilizando alguma linguagem como Java ou PHP?

Comment: No Sql mesmo, pois depois eu criou uma View e libero pro usuário.

Comment: Qual SGBD você está usando?